# Multiple upload image form doesn't save proper name of image

Tags: php, mysql, image

I've trying to put one more field in upload form to be able to upload 3 images in one form. The problem that I have is that two of the images must save different path in DB from third image.
For example `image_1` and `image_2` are saved to `http://example.com/img/` and third image into `../images/`

Currently when I fill fields with all 3 images in database I got saved this name for them - `4649d81924f1b17db1444d72ee271f6c-Array`

This is the html form

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- File Button --> 
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="image">image</label>
            <input value="<?php echo !empty($image)?$image:'';?>" id="image" name="file[]" multiple="multiple" class="input-file" type="file">
        </div>

        <!-- File Button --> 
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="rest_img_big">Image 2</label>
            <input value="<?php echo !empty($rest_img_big)?$rest_img_big:'';?>" id="rest_img_big" name="file[]" multiple="multiple" class="input-file" type="file">
        </div>

        <!-- File Button --> 
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="web_image">Image 3</label>
            <input value="<?php echo !empty($web_image)?$web_image:'';?>" id="web_image" name="file[]" multiple="multiple" class="input-file" type="file">
        </div>
</form>
```

and this is the php part for image upload

```
if ( !empty($_POST) && isSet($_POST['submit'])) 
{
      define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 20000000430);
      $permitted = array('image/jpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');

      // keep track post values       

      $fileName  = $_FILES['file']['name'];
      $tmpName   = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
      $fileSize  = $_FILES['file']['size'];
      $fileType  = $_FILES['file']['type'];                                    

      // make a new image name
      $ext = substr(strrchr($fileName, "."), 1);
      // generate the random file name
      $randName = md5(rand() * time()) . '-' .$fileName;

      // save image path
      $path = "../../img/".$randName;
      $forDB = "http://example/img/".$randName;
      if (in_array($fileType, $permitted)) 
      {
          $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $path);
          if (!$result) 
          {
                echo "Error uploading image file";
                exit;
          } 
       } 

        // update data
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql = "UPDATE images set image = ?, rest_img_big = ?, web_image = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($forDB,$forDB,$path,$user_id));
```

So any suggestion how can I fix this issue and to be able to upload 3 images at the same time?

UPDATE: Current code

```
if ( !empty($_POST) && isSet($_POST['submit'])) 
{
     define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 20000000430);
     $permitted = array('image/jpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');

     // keep track post values
     for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++){
        $fileName  = $i.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]; //get unique name
        $tmpName   = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $fileSize  = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];
        $fileType  = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];                                      

        // make a new image name
        $ext = substr(strrchr($fileName, "."), 1);
        // generate the random file name
        $randName = md5(rand() * time()) . '-' .$fileName;

        // save image path
        $web = "../../img/".$randName;
        $smallImageForApp = "http://example/img/".$randName;
        $bigImageForApp = "http://example/img/".$randName;
        if (in_array($fileType, $permitted)) 
        {
            $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $web);
            if (!$result) 
            {
                echo "Error uploading image file";
                exit;
            } 
        } 
        else {                  
            // update data
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "UPDATE images set image = ?, rest_img_big = ?, web_image = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($smallImageForApp,$bigImageForApp,$web,$user_id));
        }
```

UPDATE 2: var_dump($_FILES);

```
array(1) { 
   ["file"]=> array(5) 
   { 
   ["name"]=> array(3) 
   { 
       [0]=> string(21) "23.jpg_1418028921.jpg" 
       [1]=> string(15) "_1418028891.jpg" 
       [2]=> string(6) "78.jpg" 
   } 
   ["type"]=> array(3) 
   { 
       [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
       [1]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
       [2]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
   } 
   ["tmp_name"]=> array(3) 
   { 
       [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpfqqJG3" 
       [1]=> string(14) "/tmp/phptp9zcF" 
       [2]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpTkmuIg" 
   } 
   ["error"]=> array(3) 
   { 
       [0]=> int(0) 
       [1]=> int(0) 
       [2]=> int(0) 
   } 
   ["size"]=> array(3) 
   { 
       [0]=> int(25878) 
       [1]=> int(25878) 
       [2]=> int(35864) 
   } 
 } 
} 
 array(1) 
 { 
   //same thing 3 times
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code will only upload single image, for 3 you need to loop over `$_FILES['file']` and upload it, here is how a way to go

```
for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++){
  $fileName  = $i.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]; //get unique name
  $tmpName   = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
  $fileSize  = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];
  $fileType  = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];  

  // make a new image name
  $ext = substr(strrchr($fileName, "."), 1);
  // generate the random file name
  $randName = md5(rand() * time()) . '-' .$fileName;

  // save image path
  //check if its 3rd image change the path to '../images/' folder
  $path = ($ === 2) ? '../images/' : "../../img/".$randName;
  $forDB = "http://example/img/".$randName;
  if (in_array($fileType, $permitted)) 
  {
      $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $path);
      if (!$result) 
      {
            echo "Error uploading image file";
            exit;
      } else {
    // update data in db here, only on upload
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "UPDATE images set image = ?, rest_img_big = ?, web_image = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($forDB,$forDB,$path,$user_id));
      }
   } 

}
```

your `$fileName` is messed up `4649d81924f1b17db1444d72ee271f6c-Array` because you are appending an `array` to a string, last `Array` is showing that

**Note:** don't store full url for images in db `$forDB = "http://example/img/".$randName;` you should be storing only the name `$forDB = $randName;` that way you can move your application from domain to domain but images will not broken.

Comment: I've tried with loop like you suggest the name again is `randomstring-Array` and image isn't upload into folder. Only the name is saved into DB.

Comment: try now, i have added for loop

Comment: Ok, now the image is uploaded but 3 times same image. I mean it takes first input field image and is upload 3 times.

Comment: just add this  `$i.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];` which will prepend the index to make it different name for each image, answer update

Comment: I've updated my question with current code which still save 3 times image from first input field.

Comment: hey @JasonPaddle i hope its working now, i will suggest you to clear your uploaded file and try again with updated code, if not post your `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: updated `$path = ($ === 2) ? '../images/' : "../../img/".$randName;` to send 3rd image in `../images` folder

Comment: now error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '===' (T_IS_IDENTICAL), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' `

Comment: Updated question with var_dump. This is displayed 3 times. Now the images are in folder but they are not updated in the DB

Answer (score 1):

You need upload file one by one through a loop

```
for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++){
      $fileName  = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
      $tmpName   = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
      $fileSize  = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];
      $fileType  = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];  

     // more stuff . . . . . .
}
```